# Search for single quoted grep strings?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep

I have a string, "$server['fish_stick']"  (disregard double quotes)

I don't know how to successfully grep for an exact match for this string. I've tried many ways.

I've tried,

```
rgrep -i \$'server'\[\''fish'\_'stick'\'\] .

rgrep -i "\$server\[\'fish\_stick\'\]" .

rgrep -i '\$server\[\'fish\_stick\'\]' .
```

Is it single quotes that are causing my issue?
When I echo the first grep out it shows exactly what I want to search but returns garbage results like anything with $server in it.

Please help and explain, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are not quoting the argument being passed to grep. The only thing that needs to be escaped is \$ (if double quoted) and []. If you want the exact string (not using regex), just use fgrep (grep -F) which does exact string matching:

```
grep -F "\$server['fish_stick']"
```

Works on my system:

```
$ foo="\$server['fish_stick']"
$ echo "$foo" | grep -F "\$server['fish_stick']"
$server['fish_stick']
```

Using regex:

```
$ echo "$foo" | grep "\$server\['fish_stick'\]"
$server['fish_stick']
```

Using regex and handling nested single quotes:

```
$ echo "$foo" | grep '\$server\['\''fish_stick'\''\]'
$server['fish_stick']
```

Inside of single quotes, nested single quotes can not be not be escaped. You have to close the quotes, and then reopen it to "escape" the single quotes.

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 0):

I don't suppose you're asking how to get that string into a variable without having quoting issues. If you are, here's a way using a here-document:

```
str=$(cat <<'END'
$foo['bar']
END
)
```

To address your concern about escaping special characters for grep, you could use sed to put a backslash before any non-alphanumeric character:

```
grep "$(sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]/\\&/g' <<< "$str")" ...
```

When used with `set -x`, the grep command looks like: `grep '\$foo\[\'\''bar\'\''\]' ...`